# How to create unit test for oData get method with EnableQuery attribute

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, odata

I'm trying to find the way to write unit test for controller's method that uses oData EnableQuery attribute. For something like this one

```
        [EnableQuery]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok(Customers);
        }
```

I want to be able to apply filters, maybe via URL params and examine IActionResult.
For the beginning, I want to be able to test $top=10 filter.

I've found some code where method params includes query options. Something like

```
 public IActionResult Get(ODataQueryOptions opts)
```

[Mocking or creating pragmatically ODataQueryOptions for .NET 5 Core Controller unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66554114/mocking-or-creating-pragmatically-odataqueryoptions-for-net-5-core-controller-u)
https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1352

Is there any other way than add options as parameter?

Comment: EnableQuery is ActionFilterAttribute. So it works on a layer outside of the controller's method call.